# 1,000 sheets, data in one cell of a sheet matching data in a cell in another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 1,000 sheets, which each stand for a contract with randomly generated contract data. The counterparty ID for each contract is chosen from 1-1,000. Now I would like to assign a spread (randomly chosen between 5 and 20 basis points) to one cell of each sheet, that is the same per counterparty, i.e., if the counterparty is 333 on sheet 100 and 500 (contract number 100 and number 500), then the spread for both contracts should be the same.

How could I elegantly do this matching without VBA?

Thanks!

Comment: In which cell is the **ID?**

Comment: In which cell should the spread be placed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a new worksheet called **Spread**
2. in **A1** enter the formula `=RANDBETWEEN(5,20)`
3. copy **A1** and paste from **A2** thru **A1000**
4. copy **A1** thru **A1000** paste SpecialValues back onto the range

This column defines the spread value assigned to each contract.

Now go to a typical contract worksheet.  Say the ID is in cell **B9** and we want the assigned spread value in cell **C9.**

In **C9** enter the formula:

```
=INDEX(Spread!A1:A1000,B9)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Gary's Student! This works great when tested with 3 sheets and 3 IDs. I am confident it will also be correct with 1,000 sheets.

Comment: You are very welcome...........update **this post** if any further assistance is needed.